# How to blacklist a files which contains ZZZZZ in owncloud?

Tags: php, regex, owncloud

**Dear All,** Maybe this looks like an old thread. I have a tried different options but no luck.

I am using owncloud 10.0.9 version. We have to block the ransomware files which uploaded by a client machine. So, I have an added a 'blacklisted_files' option in config.php

> `'blacklisted_files' => ['*ZZZZZ*']` is not working.
>
> `blacklisted_files' => ['ZZZZZ.txt']` it is working, when i specified a
> full file name.

Please suggest how to exclude files which contain a ZZZZZ and it is possible to apply the same for other files as well.

Comment: Is the owncloud has a .htaccess file?

Comment: yes owncloud have a .htaccess files

Comment: @FreedomPride, Is there any other option is available from the .htaccess file.

Comment: Use firewall file, https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/enterprise/firewall/file_firewall.html

Focus on request URL containing the pattern if you don't want to use htaccess.